# How to connect two accounts in Microsoft Team

Tags: office365, microsoft-teams

I have 2 accounts one from office and one from client

I need to connect both of them to Microsoft team.

How can I connect two accounts to Microsoft Team ?

Answer (score 2):

### pre req: setup additional work account via OneDrive (update 2023 03 28)

It appears that MS fixed a *bug* since my original post, which someone from MS support told me. It just makes this a little harder to setup, but still works:

ATM it's officially not supported to be connected to >1 work accounts and thus it's not possible when trying todo so through the Win settings Accounts/Work or school" nor from the Teams App.

However, if you have the OndDrive App installed, then

1. go to settings/Account and press click "Add an Account".
2. Subsequently confirm to add the new account to your device (or smth like that)

-> and then you can see  >1 work/school accounts in "Win settings Accounts/Work or school".

Once you have that, you can

- switch between these accounts after sign out from teams app and login with either or private/work accounts.
- have them running in parallel via the env var separation, as explained below

### TLDR

A simple teams2.BAT would look like so:

```
set USERPROFILE=<new path>
start /d %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Teams\current\ teams.exe
```

### long story

There is no need to do this with a separate local account. The teams data and exe is stored locally in your user profile, ie by default in `%USERPROFILE%:\AppData\*\Microsoft\Teams`

ATM (Microsoft Teams Version 1.4.00.22976. 64-bit) this can be leveraged to install a new teams instance under a separate account, be redefining the envvar in a shell and start from that env context the teams instance.

You can install the client from the shell with that env context too, but it's also ok to just copy the files from an existing instance to the new location.

The result after running the simple start-BAT from above is, that you have 2 teams apps in the system tray from which you can open each of the instances, albeit you cant see from the icon (tooltip) which of the accounts this is, only once the app window is opened.

This works reasonably well for me since the last few days, although one of the instances dies at times w/o warning. Not sure yet what causes this - might be just my setup and one of my many custom tools that causes this.

Comment: I tried this and get an error as in the image - [here](https://ibb.co/VHnHxjB).

Comment: @HarshaJK I use this line consonantly with no a problem: `start /d%MY_ROOT%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Teams\current\ teams.exe`.
Note, MY_ROOT and USERPROFILE are identical. Have you also copied an existing teams installation into this new location ?

Comment: Hi @elonderin, Yes I did copy all the files from that folder.

Comment: @HarshaJK FYI: Yesterday i had to change my password  and hence I cant log into my 2nd teams account anymore with the desktop app - independent of whether i use the normal installation location or the above hack. However, I still can work through the webapp!? It might be that MS is messing around.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean can you access multiple tenants in Teams then yes. As well as being a user in your own tenant you can be a guest and work in several others. The same is true for your customers.
Here is the solution for running multiple account on team.

> 1) "Win + I" => Accounts => Other Users => Add someone else to this PC
>   (for example, user without Microsoft account named MSTeams, not
>   Administrator)
>
> 2) "Ctrl + Alt + Del" => Switch user
>
> 3) Login to second MSTeams user
>
> 4) Download and install MSTeams
>
> 5) Login to the MSTeams using an
>
> account with less activity and close application
>
> 6) Ctrl + Alt + Del
>   => Switch user
>
> 7) Return to your main account
>
> 8) Go to C:\WINDOWS\system32\ and find cmd.exe
>
> 9) Click "Shift + Right Mouse"
>   and chose "Run as different user" (find in google how to add it if you
>   don't have this option)
>
> 10) Login with MSTeams user
>
> 11) Write following command in the console
>
> 12)C:\Users\MSTeams\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Teams\Update.exe
>
> > --processStart "Teams.exe"
> >
> > To run MSTeams again repeat following steps 8) Go to
> >     C:\WINDOWS\system32\ and find cmd.exe 9) Click "Shift + Right Mouse"
> >     and chose "Run as different user" (find in google how to add it if you
> >     dont have this option) 10) Login with MSTeams user 11) Write following
> >     command in the console 12)
> >     C:\Users\MSTeams\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Teams\Update.exe
> >     --processStart "Teams.exe"

This steps can be optimized by PowerShell script:

## run as admin

```
if (!([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator")) { Start-Process powershell.exe "-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File `"$PSCommandPath`"" -Verb RunAs; exit }

$username = '.\MSTeams'
$password = 'YOUR_PASSWORD_OF_THE_MSTEAMS_USER.'

$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $username, $securePassword
Start-Process 'C:\Users\MSTeams\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Teams\Update.exe' '--processStart "Teams.exe"' -Credential $credential
```

Answer (score 0):

since feb 21 there is a possibility to see both accounts in the pc application, and before this date it was possible to see them in the app. You need to click on your name at the top, then you will see accounts & org, click on it and add you other account.

[image]

Comment: FYI: for Microsoft Teams Version 1.4.00.22976 (64-bit) this works only for 1 work account +1 private account but not for multiple work accounts. See my solution above to run >1 instances against diff. work accounts.

Answer (score 0):

The new version of Teams will include the ability to use multiple accounts at the same time.
If you need to use this feature right now, you can use the preview version by following these steps:

1. Open the Teams desktop application on your Windows computer.
2. Activate the Try the new Teams option in the upper left corner of the Teams application. 3.
3. Select Get it now in the pop-up dialog box. The new Teams will start installing.
4. Your Teams application will restart to open the new Teams experience. Any subsequent actions you take will take place in the new Teams by default, such as joining a Teams meeting from Outlook.

Here's what's new in this release: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-teams-blog/introducing-the-new-microsoft-teams-now-in-preview/ba-p/3774406